# Convert a variable []interface{} into variable ...interface{} in go

Tags: function, go, types, type-conversion

I am using a go mysql library to perform several database tasks. Given the fact that I want to write a wrapper package over the mysql library, I found myself into the following situation:

I have a method with the following signature:

`func(db *MySQL) Insert(query string, args ...interface{}) (int64, error)`

This method is calling the `db.Exec` function from the library which has the following signature:

`func (db *DB) Exec(query string, args ...interface{}) (Result, error)`

It seems that when I call my method `Insert("some query", 1, "test")` the `values ...interface{}` is translated into `[]interface{}` type which is incompatible to the Exec functions argument `args ...interface{}`.

Q1: By understanding this situation and having in consideration that I *can't* modify the signature of `Exec` function, how would it be possible for me to transfer the `args` from my `Insert` function to the `Exec` function?

I have tried several things to implement this but it seems I cannot achieve nor find a way to put my arguments in that function call.

Q2: Is this even possible without modifying the signature of `Exec` ?

**Edit:** This is an example of what I am trying to achieve with the above functionality:

```
func(db *MySQL) Insert(query string, values ...interface{}) (int64, error) {
    /**
     * TODO: find a way to implement the args slice
     * to implement this remember that behind Exec(_, values) there is a [] interface{} element
     * which will decompose this element inside. so by passing a values ...interface{} function won't work
     * as the values ...interface{} has another data type structure in the end
     */
    //
    if res, err := db.dbConn.Exec(query, values); err != nil {
        return -1, err
    } else {
        if lastId, err := res.LastInsertId(); err != nil {
            return -1, err
        } else {
            return lastId, nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use ORM like GORM? Its much easier

Comment: I am still a beginner in Go lang. So I am trying to find out most of the perks and mindset of this programming language. GORM seems to actually be the solution that I'm looking for so I'll be checking it. Thanks a lot for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, your problem is that when you call `Exec` from `Insert` with the same arguments, it considers `[]interface{}` as an `interface{}`. In golang, you can expand a slice with the operator `...`. This way you can pass the arguments from `Insert` to `Exec`.

```
func exec(args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(args)
}

func insert(args ...interface{}) {
    exec(args)      // Prints [[5 42]]
    exec(args...)   // Prints [5 42]
}

func main() {
    insert(5, "42")
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Indeed. I forgot about the thing that I can expand the argument list! Thanks a lot!!!!